# How to display 2 fragments side by side in activity with Navigation Component

Tags: java, android, kotlin, navigation, components

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8qHL.png)

How can I show 2 fragment in the same activity using the navigation component, as shown in the sample photo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the way understand navigation component it doesnt support that and it shouldn't. whole point of it is to have one NavHostFragment which with nav_graph will be responsible for navigating in your app. it cant host two fragments at the same time. now you have two options. you can have two NavHostFragment with two nav_graphs associated with it. or you can have some kind of ListDetailsFragment and make it manage list and list item details showing. you can create two separate child Fragment(ListFragment and DetailsFragment) inside of that fragment to manage things easily. personally I would suggest last one.

Comment: Thanks, I created it in a standard way and enabled it to communicate with the interface.